# Unit Test for a Method that Changes the State of a private Field

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

So, I have the following problem (using C#):

I have two private fields in a class, one that saves the original state of a field and one that saves the updated state.

I now want to write a method that basically takes the original state, copies it to the updated state and changes some of its content.

So far I have implemented that as a void method which just changes the state of the fields (if needed). These fields will later be used by another method.

I don't think I will have any trouble with the implementation, but I'm trying to write unit tests for this method (with MSTest) and can't see how I can properly test this.

The thing I would really need to test is whether given the input parameters the content of the field has changed compared to its original state or not. Since both fields are private I can neither access the original state to set a value for the unit test nor can I access the fields to use for any comparisons for any assertions.

The easiest way would be to expose all these fields with public properties, but I really have no use for public properties apart from the unit tests. Another way would be to rewrite the method to return the updated state, but that still doesn't help me in setting the original state to what I need for the tests.

Any ideas or best practices on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PrivateObject.GetField()` to retrieve the final state of that field. ([privateObject members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

This is the better route than modifying the API merely to make it test-able.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. I actually changed the method to take in the original state and return the updated state, which makes it testable on its own. I'm not sure if I'm happy with that solution, so I might return to one of the former iterations and update the test to use PrivateObject instead. Anyway this is very good to know for future tests.

Answer (score 2):

What *visible* change does it make if the fields are copied properly? Presumably it affects the behaviour of the object in *some* way... so that's the ideal thing to test.

Sometimes it can be worth adding internal helper methods for the sake of testability (in conjunction with [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)) but ideally, testing the changes to visible behaviour/state is a less fragile approach.

Comment: The visible change isn't apparent until much later when another method uses these fields to write out an xml file. Basically there are methods to read the original xml, make changes to specific nodes and write out the updated xml. I managed to build it so that I can test all the methods by themselves, but this one is somewhere in between and would in the current state need both the method to retrieve the original state AND the one that writes out the changes to make the changes visible.